# Does Haskell have implicit pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, syntax, function-call

Take this example:

```
module Main where

main = print (reverseWords "lol")
  
reverseWords :: String -> [String]  
reverseWords = words
```

`reverseWords` function is not pattern matching against any argument here yet the function runs and outputs `"[lol]"`.

I have two questions here:

1. How does Haskell know whether or not I am invoking the `words` function against the input to `reverseWords`? In this syntax it looks like I am simply returning the function `words`.
2. Why is this able to run successfully even though I have not provided any input arguments in the pattern to `reverseWords`?

Comment: I have found that it helps to not think in terms of *doing* (such as "returning") but in terms of *being*. When I see `reverseWords = words`, I think "`reverseWords` *is* `words`"

Answer (score 8):

You're just saying that `reverseWords` *is* the function `words`. Anywhere that `reverseWords` appears, it can be replaced by the function `words`. So `print (reverseWords "lol")` is exactly equivalent to `print (words "lol")`. Basically, you have this new function `reverseWords` that takes a `String` argument just like `words` does and simply passes that argument to `words`, returning whatever `words` returns for that argument. Your definition of `reverseWords` is equivalent to:

```hs
reverseWords :: String -> [String]
reverseWords s = words s
```

Given all of that, `reverseWords` is a misleading name because it's not doing anything differently than `words`. So, you're not really doing anything useful at all, just renaming something. A better example would be this:

```hs
reverseWords :: String -> [String]
reverseWords = reverse . words
```

where `reverse` is some other function you compose with `words` using the composition operator `(.)` to make a new function that does something useful. That's called point-free style, where you define new functions by combining other functions without referring to any arguments. That definition is equivalent to:

```hs
reverseWords :: String -> [String]
reverseWords s = reverse (words s)
```

Comment: My be worth mentioning eta-reduction.

Comment: how are these equivalent? to my understanding reverseWords returns a function definition words (so invoking reverseWords should only return the function words (without it being invoked))

Comment: @AndrewTang They are not only equivalent, they are equal. You can replace one by the other. They are equal, because you say so `reverseWords = words`. The function that is returned by `reverseWords` is the same function that is returned by `words`. It's like saying x = y, y = z, z = 1. Even if you decide to store that as x -> y, y -> z, z->1 the all come out to the same value and the way you stored that fact is irrelevant. (To be more precise, `reverseWords` and `words` could still differ in their types, ie `words` could have a more general type. But you can still replace one by the other.)

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring a new function `reverseWords`. First you declare it's type:

```
reverseWords :: String -> [String]
```

So it's going to be a function that takes a string and returns a list of strings.

Now there are two ways we can approach this. The first is to write a **rule** that says that when `reverseWords` receives some argument, the result is an expression (probably involving calling other functions and using the argument) for a list of strings. Like this:

```
reverseWords s = words s
```

This says "expressions of the form `reverseWords s` are defined to be equal to `words s`". So then the compiler knows that `reverseWords "lol"` is equal to `words "lol"`. The function `reverseWords` is implicitly defined by the rules we write for it<sup>1</sup>.

But there's another way we can think about this. I assume you're perfectly comfortable with how this works:

```
myFavouriteNumber :: Integer
myFavouriteNumber = 28
```

We first declare that `myFavouriteNumber` will be of type `Integer`, and then define it by just writing down an integer.

Well, functions are first class values in Haskell, which means we don't only have to define them using dedicated special-purpose syntax. If we can make definitions of type `Integer` by just writing down an integer, we should be able to make definitions of type `String -> [String]` by just writing down something with that type, rather than writing down rules. That is what is going on in this form:

```
reverseWords = words
```

Rather than writing a rule for what the result of `reverseWords` will be when it's applied to something, we just write down what `reverseWords` **is**. In this case, we tell the compiler that `reverseWords` is defined to be equal to `words`. That still lets the compiler know that `reverseWords "lol"` is equal to `words "lol"`, but it does it just by looking at `reverseWords` part; it could work that out even without looking at the `"lol"`.

Furthermore, we can also write definitions like this:

```
two :: Integer
two = 1 + 1
```

Here instead of defining `two` as equal to some pre-existing thing, we *calculate* its value (from other pre-existing things: `1` and `+`). And because functions are first class, we can do the same thing:

```
reversedWords :: String -> [String]
reversedWords = reverse . words
```

Here we don't say `reversedWords` is equal to an existing function, instead we *calculate* the function that `reverseWords` is what you get by calling the composition operator `.` on the pre-existing functions `reverse` and `words`. But we're still calculating the *function* (of type `String -> [String]`), not the function's *result* (of type `[String]`).

---

So to answer your questions:

> How does haskell know whether or not I am invoking the "words" function against the input to reverseWords? In this syntax it looks like I am simply returning the function "words"

Yes, you **are** just returning the function `words`. But you're "returning" it as the *function* `reversedWords` itself (before it's applied to anything), **not** as the *result* of `reversedWords` when it's applied. And that's how Haskell knows that the `words` function is to receive the input to `reverseWords`; `reverseWords` is *equal* to `words`, so any time you pass some input to `reverseWords` you're really passing it to `words`.

> Why is this able to run successfully even though I have not provided any input arguments in the pattern to reverseWords?

Because you defined the function `reverseWords`. You defined it by declaring it equal to some other existing function, so it does whatever that function does. Writing rules for function results (based on arguments) is not the only way to define a function.

The fact that you didn't provide a name for the argument of `reverseWords` in your definition is exactly how Haskell knows that's what you're doing. If you're defining a function of type `A -> B` and you give a name to the argument, then the right hand side must be something of type `B`. If you don't, then the right hand side must be something of type `A -> B`.<sup>2</sup>

But for your tile question:

> Does haskell have implicit pattern matching?

I'm not sure how to answer that, because none of this discussion has involved pattern matching at all. You can use pattern matching to define functions in Haskell, but that's not what is going on here.

---

<sup>1</sup> Okay, in this case `reverseWords` is pretty *explicitly* defined by the rule, but in general functions can be defined using multiple rules using pattern matching and guards, and with auxilliary `where` definitions; the actual value of the function is sort of an emergent property of all the rules (and knowledge of how they'll be tried in order top-down) and `where` clauses.

<sup>2</sup> This logic works regardless of what `A` and `B` are. In particular, `B` could be something with more arrows in it! That is exactly how functions with multiple arguments work in Haskell. A function like:

```
foo :: Int -> String -> (Int, String)
```

could be defined by either:

1. Writing a rule taking two arguments (an `Int` and a `String`), with a right hand side of type `(Int, String)`
2. Writing a rule taking one argument (an `Int`), with a right hand side of type `String -> (Int, String)`
3. Writing a direct definition with no arguments, with a right hand side of type `Int -> String -> (Int, String)`

The pattern is clear; each time you add an argument to your rule, the RHS has a type that strips off one more arrow (starting from the left).

All 3 options produce a function `foo` with the same type that you can call the same way. The internal definition of the function doesn't matter to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

`reverseWord` indeed "returns" `words` without calling it, and so `reverseWords s` becomes `words s` -- since `reverseWords` had returned `words`, the *call* `reverseWords s` had become the *call* `words s`.

It's like having the definition `foo() { bar }` in more conventional syntax, then `foo()(x)` === `bar(x)`.